# Building a Code Generator in ruby.. Where to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation, scaffolding

I've been thinking about starting an open source  admin panel for rails using the cappuccino JavaScript / Objective-J web framework..

How would I get started?

Are there any resources you can point me to, that explain dynamic scaffolding like code generation?

Thanks and looking forward to collaborating if anyones interested?

Daniel

Comment: Could start by looking at how Ruby on Rails does it: https://github.com/rails/rails

Comment: Depends, where will you base the generated code on? Database, XML, Diagram?

Comment: Yeah I thought that may be a good place to start... I'm gonna base it on rails models :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look @ [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin).  It is a port of Merb Admin.  It's still pretty young, but may give you ideas on the approach.

[ActiveScaffold](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold) has been around for a while too which may be another good reference project.